# Can't access from Objective-c to swift's member properties

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have swift class like this.

```
class Note: NSObject{
    var soundUrl: URL!
    var sPosi: Int!
    var contNum: Int!
}
```

then from Objective-c I would like to access these members.

However There is difference betwwen URL type and Int type.

I think I include correctly in both (.h) (.m) file

in Quesion.h

```
@class Note
@interface Question : NSObject{
    Note * QNotes[70];
}
```

in Question.m

```
#import "QuesionNote-Swift.h"

- (id)init
{
    // QNote array correctly declared and have each Note class instance.
     int i = QNotes[i].sPosi; // Question.m:135:26: Property 'sPosi' not found on object of type 'Note *'

      int j = QNotes[Q].contNum; //Question.m:145:37: Property 'contNum' not found on object of type 'Note *'

     NSURL * k = QNotes[QPosiNum].soundUrl // it doesn't show compile error!!
```

Comment: May be make Int non-optional.

Comment: P.S. Nobody using instance variables in .h-files in 2017.

Comment: I changed like this `var sPosi = 0` `var contNum = 0` it works. I am not sure why optional URL  works though. This objective-c class is written a few years ago. So using interface